# Why can't I access my viewmodel from within a computed property?

Tags: knockout.js

For a single-page application I need to use multiple ViewModels at the same time, but can't seem to access a different ViewModel from within a computed property of another.

An (extremely simplified) example is: (http://jsfiddle.net/5t2tb/14/)

html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Search.results">
    <a data-bind="text: id, css: { IsInBookshelf: IsInBookshelf() }"></a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModels = {
    Search: new SearchViewModel()
};

function SearchViewModel() {
    this.results = ko.observableArray([new Book(123), new Book(456)]);
}

function Book(id) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);

    this.IsInBookshelf = ko.computed(function () {
        alert(ViewModels);
        return id%2==0;
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModels);
```

style

```
.IsInBookshelf {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I can't figure out why var ViewModels in computed method IsInBookshelf is undefined, as it is supposed to be a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because at the time that `ko.computed` is being executed (as part of `new Book` as part of `new SearchViewModel`), the value has not yet been assigned to `ViewModels` since its still being "executed".  If you need to have a reference to `ViewModels` in your computed observable, you can create the `ViewModels` object and then set the `Search` property separately:

```
var ViewModels = {};
ViewModels.Search = new SearchViewModel();
```

[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t2tb/15/)

Note that at `ViewModel.Search` creation time, `ViewModels` will not have a `Search` property, but when the `ko.computed` is triggered at a later point, it will.

Comment: otherwise, you can use the `deferEvaluation` option of a computed like: `this.IsInBookShelf = ko.computed({ read: function() { //yourlogic }, deferEvaluation: true }, this);` This will make it so the first evaluation does not happen until someone actually accesses it.

Comment: @go-oleg: Really straightforward javascript mistake I made there... Thank you for pointing this out, and an easy way to fix it! Go! oleg. ;)

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Very interesting different approach that I need to look into. Thanks!